# Close form after selecting row in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVYzk.png)
I've got a form `[frmProducts]` with some TextBox on it and a button `[btnSearch]`.
When the button is clicked, it opens a new form `[frmProductSearch]` with only 1 DataGridView `[dtgvProductSearch]` and a button `[btnClose]` that closes the `[frmProductSearch]`.

I want to click the search button, navigate trough the datagrid, press `Enter` on the selected row and send the data from the DataBase to the other form `[frmProducts]`  so I can alter the info.

Comment: please provide sample code and more explanation

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example for this case

**frmProducts:**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var frmSearch = new frmSearchProducts
            {
                ProductName = textBox1.Text.Trim(),
                ProductCategory = textBox2.Text.Trim()
            };

            if(frmSearch.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // get selected rows...
                var selectedRows = frmSearch.SelectedProducts;
            }        
        }
```

**frmProductSearch:**

```
private List<Product> _selectedProducts;

        public List<Product> SelectedProducts
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedProducts;
            }
        }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string ProductCategory { get; set; }

        private void frmSearchProducts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _selectedProducts = new List<Product>();

            this.KeyPreview = true;

            //TODO: do search product            
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Enter:
                    {
                        //TODO: Get your selected on gridview...
                        _selectedProducts = new List<Product>();

                        // set dialog result
                        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                        // close form
                        Hide();
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thats was exactly what I needed. But there's any problem if I close instead of hiding?